# Erro na formação do título do site

Tags: php, html

Estou com um problema no site de um cliente, ele tem várias páginas de produtos e eu criei uma página chamada `mostra_produto.php`, porém a função que chama o título está retornando com problema.

**ERRO:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CÓDIGO:**

```
<title>
     <?php echo($nomeproduto)?> .' - Vendas'); ?>
</title>
```

Comment: Uma forma equivalente, mas mais compacta, seria `<?= "{$nomeproduto} - Vendas" ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente desta forma:

```
<title>
     <?php echo $nomeproduto.' - Vendas'; ?>
</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás a fazer a concatenação mal, essa tag de fechar o `php` deve aparecer mais tarde, no final da concatenação:

```
<?php echo $nomeproduto.' - Vendas'; ?>
```